# Non-default compilers (GCC or Vanilla-Clang) on macOS High Sierra linking issue

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, linker, clang

I am working on a currently mac based hobby project that involves some parallelization, for which I'd like to use OpenMP since this seems quite portable and relatively easy to implement in my case. After some online reading, I found out that gcc and clang can both compile with -fopenmp in their current versions. The default macOS compiler included with Xcode is stripped of this functionality, though. So, I installed both gcc 7 and clang 5 on my macOS. Since my project is built via CMake, I have written the following makefile.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Project C CXX)

#SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/local/bin/gcc-7)
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/bin/gcc-7)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O2 -mavx2 -march=haswell -flto=thin -g0")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lpthread")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.65 COMPONENTS filesystem system thread atomic chrono regex)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc imgcodecs calib3d)

set(HDF5_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES ON)
set(HDF5_ROOT /usr/local/HDF_GROUP/HDF5/1.10.0/)
FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(Project /path/to/many/files..)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Project ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Project ${OpenCV_LIBS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Project ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
```

In this version with the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER setting disabled, the code compiles, links, and runs without a hitch. As soon as I set CMake to use gcc or vanilla-clang for the exact same project without any further changes, compiling finishes without any trouble but linking fails. The linker reports hundreds of missing symbols ranging from a few OpenCV symbols to mostly libc++ things like

```
"std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

Therefore, I am obviously missing something fundamental. With vanilla-clang, I tried adding -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib to point the linker to the libs that came with clang. Unfortunately, this changed nothing.

I'd appreciate any hints on the matter. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the gcc compiler driver to perform the link change the compiler to 'g++' from 'gcc', g++ automatically brings in the standard c++ library where gcc does not, or add -lstdc++, there may be others required but using g++ as the compiler driver is usually easier.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This definitely decreases the number of missing symbols. Interestingly, the missing symbols are still refering to basic c++ functionality like "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()" and such but it's always either boost or OpenCV refering to them. Do I have to recompile both libs with gcc as well?

Comment: Update: This worked for LLVM/clang 5.0. GCC still seems to struggle with libraries previously compiled by Apple's clang. Anyway, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it took one complete day to find the solution. I am using Mac-Sierra 10.13.4. I want to use Opencv3 (I think the same problem also appears for opencv2) and openMP. I was actually using Clion as the IDE (CLion uses cmake to configure the project unlike other IDE), so I have to write the CMakeLists.txt file.

There was a conflict of using gcc as the compiler for openCV and openMP. If you use gcc as the compiler then it gives error for opencv as :

> imwrite() on OS X error: Undefined symbols

You need to specifically use llvm compiler on OS X to resolve this issue. Following, I am giving the correct code for using OpenCV and OpenMP on Mac-Sierra:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyOpenCVTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(MyOpenCVTest main.cpp)

# set("OpenCV_DIR" "/modules/opencv/3.4.1/share/OpenCV/")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/")

set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/include/")
set(OpenCV_LIBS "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv@3/lib/")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()


set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/bin/clang++")
set(OPENMP_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/lib")
set(OPENMP_INCLUDES "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/include")

OPTION (USE_OpenMP "Use OpenMP to enamble <omp.h>" ON)

# Find OpenMP
if(APPLE AND USE_OpenMP)
    if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_C "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
        set(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-fopenmp=libomp -Wno-unused-command-line-argument")
        set(OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES "libomp" "libgomp" "libiomp5")
        set(OpenMP_libomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES})
        set(OpenMP_libgomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES})
        set(OpenMP_libiomp5_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES})
    endif()
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_CXX "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-fopenmp=libomp -Wno-unused-command-line-argument")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES "libomp" "libgomp" "libiomp5")
        set(OpenMP_libomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES})
        set(OpenMP_libgomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES})
        set(OpenMP_libiomp5_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES})
    endif()
endif()

if(USE_OpenMP)
    find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
endif(USE_OpenMP)

if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    include_directories("${OPENMP_INCLUDES}")
    link_directories("${OPENMP_LIBRARIES}")
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    # set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif(OPENMP_FOUND)


include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( MyOpenCVTest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyOpenCVTest opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs)
```

You might want to set e.g. set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lpthread") such that the linker automatically detects the appropriate pthread library

Do

> brew reinstall llvm

to install llvm compiler.
Please note that, you can't use gcc compiler on Mac-Sierra for your project which needs openMP and also openCV. You need to use llvm compiler.

Verify the correct locations of llvm and opencv installation directory.